# Using Custom Simple Mapi DLL without installing Outlook

Tags: c++, outlook, messaging, mapi

i have written an custom DLL which uses Simple Mapi functions.

I have set the Registry Keys and it works so far... I can use the file context menu in Windows --> send to mail recipient and pass the attachment to my application to process it.

I read the "Outlook Mapi Reference" by Microsoft but i am confused now.

Is there a way to get my DLL working on a simple computer (with Win 7 or 10) without installing any version of MS Outlook?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1 May 2013 Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39045).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed "MS Exchange Server Mapi Client" on a clean Windows 10 installation without Outlook/Office or anything else installed. After that i inserted the Registry Keys to add my application as Mail-Client and to interact with the mailto protocol... It's not working for me. I still get the error "there is no email program associated to perform the requested action".